# Show or hide the element or component by clicking a button

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I can't change the `state` by clicking a button.

This is my code below:

```
changeAllFun = () => {
    this.setState = ({
      showBadTable: '1',
    })
  }

  changeBadFun = () => {
    this.setState = ({
      showBadTable: '0',
    })
  }

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showBadTable: '1',
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div>
          <h1>All or Bad</h1>

          <RaisedButton style={styles.TopButtonStyle} disableTouchRipple={true}
                        disabled={false} label="All"
                        onTouchTap={this.changeAllFun}
                        primary={true}></RaisedButton>
          <RaisedButton style={styles.TopButtonStyle} disableTouchRipple={true}
                        disabled={false} label="Bad"
                        onTouchTap={this.changeBadFun}
                        primary={true}></RaisedButton>

          {(this.state.showBadTable == '0') ? (<h2>all</h2>) : (<h2>bad</h2>)}

          {this.state.showBadTable}

        </div>
    );
  }
```

`this.state.showBadTable`  is `1`  all time.
I have looked a few answers on Stack Overflow. I can't find the different between my code and the answers. Why my code does not work?

Comment: Change `this.setState = ({` to `this.setState({`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change

```
 this.setState = ({
      showBadTable: '0',
    })
```

to

```
 this.setState ({
      showBadTable: '0',
    })
```